# Export DDL of View in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a view vw_Monitor in database

how can I export DDL of creation of this table into a file in Oracle SQL Developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Connections window
2. Expand Connection
3. Expand Views
4. Right click on the view and select export
5. From the pop up window, specify filename (default name being export.sql)
6. Click next and then finish

Comment: Thanks, can you also tell me how can I do this with PL/SQL code?

Comment: Sorry, not much idea how to do that with pl sql

Comment: This is not correct, there should be an option when you right click that states "Use as template" that will provide the DDL. The export to SQL will more than likely give you the insert statements for the data available in the view, but not the definition (where clauses, etc.).